# Error: ER_NO_DB_ERROR: No database selected in Node.js?

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, express

I want to create **sql** table from **node.js** server. However, I am encountering this error:

*(node:13560) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: ER_NO_DB_ERROR: No database selected*

I tried to add: **use stan_sehk;**
where stan_sehk is the name of the schema. However I got another error:
*(node:12468) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax;*

The thing is that the select statements work but create statements give errors. The same is true for *CREATE VIEW* stataments.

```
//MY db_config.json file

{
"mysql":{
  "host":  "localhost",
  "port": 3306,
  "acquireTimeout": 30000,
  "user": "appuser",
  "password" :  "abc123",
  "database": ""
},
  "redis":{
    "port"    : 6379,
    "host"    : "127.0.0.1"
  }
}
```

//My mysql_access.js file

```
const mysql = require('mysql');
const fs = require('fs');
const json = require('json');

const config_param = fs.readFileSync('./data_access/db_config.json', 'utf-8');
const config_param_json = JSON.parse(config_param);

const pool = mysql.createPool({
    host: config_param_json.mysql.host,
    port: config_param_json.mysql.port,
    acquireTimeout: config_param_json.mysql.acquireTimeout,
    user: config_param_json.mysql.user,
    password: config_param_json.mysql.password,
    dateStrings: true 
});

let query = function( sql, values) {
    return new Promise(( resolve, reject ) => {
        pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
            if (err) {
                reject( err )
            } else {
                connection.query(sql, values, ( err, rows) => {
                    if ( err ) {
                        reject( err )
                    } else {
                        resolve(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(rows)))
                    }
                    connection.release()
                })
            }
        })
    })
};

module.exports = {query};
```

Query for error 1:

```
let sql = `create table if not exists todos(
                      id int primary key auto_increment,
                      title varchar(255)not null,
                      completed tinyint(1) not null default 0
                  )`;
let sql_call = {
        sql: sql,
        sql_value: null
};


let sql_result = await mysql_access.query(sql_call.sql, sql_call.sql_value);
console.log(sql_result[11]);
```

Error Message:

```
(node:10640) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: ER_NO_DB_ERROR: No database selected
```

Query For error 2:

```
let sql = `use stan_sehk; create table if not exists todos(
                      id int primary key auto_increment,
                      title varchar(255)not null,
                      completed tinyint(1) not null default 0
                  )`;

let sql_call = {
         sql: sql,
         sql_value: null
};
let sql_result = await mysql_access.query(sql_call.sql, sql_call.sql_value);
console.log(sql_result[11]);
```

Error Message:

```
(node:12468) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'create table if not exists todos(id int primary key a' at line 1
```

Please help me if there is something that I am not doing correctly. And as I said, *SELECT* queries work but *CREATE* queries give the above errors. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: As you mansion that after giving proper Schema name you can SELECT data, but having trouble with the CREATE statement, I feel there are permission related issue with the user 'appuser'.

Comment: @mkRabbani Thanks for your reply. I also thought that that is the problem but even changing the user to root didn't solve the issue. Also in mysql workbench all the queries are working even for the user 'appuser'. Still can't understand why that error occurs.